# How to change image in a div with select tag?

Tags: javascript, html, image, select, src

Im actually making my own telephone input menu and my code structure looks something like below:

```
<select id-"select_code">
    <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India</option>
    <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">US</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK</option>
</select>
```

How do I the modify image source in following section by selecting a Text/value of `<Select> tag`
and changing `{data-countryCode}` in image url by actual ***data-countryCodes*** in lowercase

```
<div class="image">
  <img id="flag_img" src="https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/{data-countryCode}.webp" id="img-change">
</div>
```

```
    <script>
      var select = document.getElementById("select_code")
      select.addEventListner("click", function changeImage(){
          document.getElementById("flag-img").src = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/ + {what to do here?} + .webp`
}
    </script>
```

Comment: use a change event handler

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? Can you share your code, add it to your question? (Which is JavaScript, I assume, given the tag in the question).

Comment: hi, i have made some edit to clarification. I hope it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind change event handler to the select tag and change `src` according to the change.

```js
const img = document.querySelector('#img-change');
const select = document.querySelector('#country');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  img.src = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${this.selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase()}.webp`
})
```

```html
<select id="country">
  <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India</option>
  <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">US</option>
  <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK</option>
</select>


<div class="image">
  <img src="https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/in.webp" id="img-change">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `change` event to the `select`. getFlag will create the flag url and will set it to the `src` of the image which was initially empty. On `change` this `getFlag` is again called to get the `data` attribute from the selected option. NOte the use of `template literal` in `flagURL` constant

```js
function getFlag() {
  const url = document.getElementById('phoneSelect').selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode;
  const flagURL = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${url.toLowerCase()}.webp`
  document.getElementById('img-change').setAttribute('src', flagURL)

}

document.getElementById('phoneSelect').addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
  getFlag();
});

getFlag()
```

```html
<select id='phoneSelect'>
  <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India</option>
  <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">US</option>
  <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK</option>
</select>


<div class="image">
  <img src='' id="img-change">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JavaScript.
Add a eventlistener on change to your selection and then set the src of the image according to the selected option.

```js
const selection = document.querySelector('#countryCodeSelection');
const image = document.querySelector('#img-change')

selection.onchange = (ev) => {
  const index = selection.selectedIndex;
  const countryCode = selection.options[index].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase();

  image.src = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${countryCode}.webp`
};
```

```html
<select id="countryCodeSelection">
  <option disabled selected value>select country</option>
  <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India</option>
  <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">US</option>
  <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK</option>
</select>

<div class="image">
  <img id="img-change">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

your HTML

```
<select id="chooseCountry">
    <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India</option>
    <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">US</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK</option>
</select>

<div class="image" id="imageRelativeCountry">
    <img src="https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/in.webp" id="img-change">
</div>
```

js code

```
const chooseCountrySelect =  document.getElementById("chooseCountry");

chooseCountrySelect.addEventListener("change",function (e) {

    let language = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-countryCode");
    const imgElm = document.querySelector("#imageRelativeCountry img");

    language = language.toLowerCase();
    imgElm.setAttribute("src",`https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${language}.webp`);

});
```